# Initialize CollectionView with a collection reference

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

In my initialize function of a CollectionView Backbone Marionette object, I'm doing the following:

```
this.collection_addresses = new AddressCollectionView({
    el: 'ul.addresses',
    collection: options.user.get("addresses")
});
```

However the `AddressCollectionView` is never updated whenever the object referenced in `options.user.get("addresses")` is changed, I thought Marionnette is handling this automatically. The user object is updated using a fetch. Any thoughts?

**Edit #1**
Just to clarify the collection view is like this

```
var AddressCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: AddressItemView,
    tagName: 'ul'
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: From the docs it seems you still need to "listen to" the collection events

Comment: @AstDerek why? the collectionview initailizer usually listens to the add/remove/reset

Comment: you aren't adding/removing/resetting the collection. You are modifying a model on that collection.

Answer (score 0):

from the v1.0.3 source code, here are the events the collectionview listens to

```
_initialEvents: function(){
    if (this.collection){
      this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.addChildView, this);
      this.listenTo(this.collection, "remove", this.removeItemView, this);
      this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render, this);
    }
  },
```

A collectionView accepts an itemView view object definition, (not an instance). This itemView is initialized with the model for each item in the collection by the collectionview. I would extend marionette's  itemview class, and listen to your change event on your model there, and inject that itemview view object definition, (not an instance) into the collectionview.

Comment: you itemView needs to listen to the model change event in it's initialize block, and you should be done then.